# How to prevent the nasty side effects when decorating angulars $exceptionHandler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

For custom server side logging I'm wrapping angulars $exceptionHandler like this as descibed at many places including stackoverflow and the angular docs (there are variations but they're basically doing the same thing):

```
loggingModule.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', function ($delegate, ExceptionLoggingService) {
        return function () {
            // Call our own ExceptionLoggingService
            ExceptionLoggingService.apply(null, arguments);
            // Call the original
            $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
        };
    });
});
```

This however leads to the $exceptionHandler not throwing any errors during karma/jasmine unit tests.

This can be explemified by using [this test taken from the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$exceptionHandler), which runs fine when the module is not decorated, but which all fail, when it is:

```
beforeEach(module('logging'));

describe('$exceptionHandlerProvider', function () {
    // testing standard behaviour of $exceptionHandler
    // see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$exceptionHandler
    it('should capture log messages and exceptions', function () {
        module(function ($exceptionHandlerProvider) {
            $exceptionHandlerProvider.mode('log');
        });

        inject(function ($log, $exceptionHandler, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $log.log(1);
            });
            $timeout(function () {
                $log.log(2);
                throw 'banana peel';
            });
            $timeout(function () {
                $log.log(3);
            });
            expect($exceptionHandler.errors).toEqual([]);
            expect($log.assertEmpty());
            $timeout.flush();
            expect($exceptionHandler.errors).toEqual(['banana peel']);
            expect($log.log.logs).toEqual([[1], [2], [3]]);
        });
    });
});
```

Any idea how to fix this behaviour? Also [check out this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/X3m7ig1v2JCBfXvIb6uA?p=preview).

I'm using angular#1.3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$exceptionHandler` function from `ngMock` has an `error` property that points to an array.

The function that your decorator returns does not have that property:

```
return function () {

  ExceptionLoggingService.apply(null, arguments);

  $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
};
```

So this will for example fail:

```
expect($exceptionHandler.errors).toEqual([]);
```

Here is an implementation that hopefully should work:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', 'ExceptionLoggingService',
    function($delegate, ExceptionLoggingService) {

      var decoratedExceptionHandler = function() {

        ExceptionLoggingService.apply(this, arguments);

        return $delegate.apply(this, arguments);
      };

      for (var key in $delegate) {

        if (!$delegate.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        decoratedExceptionHandler[key] = $delegate[key];
      }

      return decoratedExceptionHandler;    
    }
  ]);
});
```

As a note, you should always make sure to do this when decorating. The real implementation of `$exceptionHandler` might not have any properties right now, but you never know if it will have in the future. The `$templateRequest` service is one example of where you must do this, as it has properties used internally to make view animations work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent answer. There is still a minor issue. I get the error 'Expected [ [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.stack.split') ], [ 3 ] ] to equal [ [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ] ].' I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: No problem :) I just tried and it worked for me. Can you replicate it in a Plunker?

Comment: Can you try without the call to `ExceptionLoggingService`? I don't know what your implementation of it looks like and just used a dummy when I tested.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if I leave it out completly. I created a plunkr, which weirdly lets the other condition fail, than the one in my local tests:
http://plnkr.co/edit/X3m7ig1v2JCBfXvIb6uA?p=preview

Comment: Remove `var args = [].slice.call(arguments);` and pass `arguments` to `$delegate.apply` instead.

Comment: Otherwise you are passing the arguments from the wrong function.

Comment: Works flawlessly so far. Thank you very much! This whole thing is a good reminder to treat with $decorators more carefully.